# Match route on querystring

Tags: routes, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I'm in the process of converting a legacy web api application to mvc 6/.net core and I've run into a problem that I can't resolve.  In web api you could define a single route that mapped to multiple actions and the correct action would be invoked based on the query string.  For instance:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Foo",
            routeTemplate: GetRoute("api/Foo"),
            defaults: new
            {
                controller = "Foo",
                action = "Bar",
                name = "foobar"
            }
        );
public class Foo : ApiController
{
    [AcceptVerbs("GET")]
    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> Bar(int id)

    {
        //process request
    }

    [AcceptVerbs("GET")]
    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> Bar(string message)

    {
        //process request
    }
}
```

foo/bar?id=1 and foo/bar?message=some message would get routed to the correct methods.  This does not work with mvc 6.  I've tried to use Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim but it didn't work, at least not with attribute routing.  Are there any options other than creating a single action with all possible parameters and then doing null checks?  Unfortunately changing the routes is not an option as they are currently being used by client applications.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an inline constraint to specify the correct route to use.
This is a working example

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class FooController : Controller
{

    // GET api/foo/bar/123
    [HttpGet("{id:int}")]
    public int Bar(int id)
    {
        return id;
    }

    // GET api/foo/bar/abc
    [HttpGet("{message:alpha}")]
    public string Bar(string message)
    {
        return $"String value \"{message}\"";
    }
}
```

Comment: That would work but I cannot use api/foo/bar/abc   I need to use api/foo?message=abc   and   api/foo?id=123

Comment: You can use a rewrite url engine to transform request from api/foo?message=abc to api/foo/bar/abc and api/foo?id=123 to api/boo/bar/123.

Comment: That would work!  Can you point me to any resources that would show how to do that?  I'm not familiar with rewrite url engines.

Comment: you car read this for iis http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

Comment: Is there a way to do this that doesn't involve the hosting environment?  This application will not be hosted in IIS anyway.  Seems like what I need to do is alter the way MVC matches routes.

Answer (score 0):

This could be good for your problem

middleware :

```
public class RewriteUrl
{
    RequestDelegate _next;
    public RewriteUrl(RequestDelegate next )
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        var path = context.Request.Path.ToUriComponent();

        if (string.Equals(path, "/api/foo", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            var querystring = context.Request.QueryString.ToUriComponent();
            //remove ? at the top of string
            querystring = querystring.Substring(1);
            var querystringVector = querystring.Split('&');
            for(var i=0; i<querystringVector.Length; i++)
            {
                var querystringValue = querystringVector[i];
                var querystringValueVector = querystringValue.Split('=');
                if ( querystringValueVector[0].Equals("id", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
                    querystringValueVector[0].Equals("message", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    context.Request.Path = "/Api/foo/bar/" + querystringValueVector[1];
                }
            }
        }

        await _next.Invoke(context);
    }
}

public static class RewriteUrlExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseRewriteUrl(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<RewriteUrl>();
    }
}
```

into your startup class :

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        app.UseRewriteUrl();

        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

your controller :

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class FooController : Controller
{

    // GET api/foo/bar/123
    [HttpGet("bar/{id:int}")]
    public int Bar(int id)
    {
        return id;
    }

    // GET api/foo/bar/abc
    [HttpGet("bar/{message:alpha}")]
    public string Bar(string message)
    {
        return $"String value \"{message}\"";
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, thank you.  I'll give this approach a try.